# installed python 3.8 recently and i am trying to install py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py using the idle

Tags: python, discord

so I keep trying to install discord.py via windows with this command as its shown on GitHub with python 3.8 idle

```
>>> py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

but I just get nothing but invalid syntax here and I'm unsure as to why its saying this, I've followed this guide step by step but nothing works

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed1p3.png)

okay ive also run the command via powershell and cmd.exe and both have not worked
just attempted the sub process route you suggested and all I get a is  file not found error

Comment: note that the `>>>` is not part of the command

Comment: also do you have a `discord.py` in the folder? what guide are you talking about?

Comment: alright i have resolved the issue i only needed a simple pip install discord.py command rather than the py -3  -,m commands

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of console: windows and python.

Windows commands are typed into the windows console (`cmd.exe` from the start menu). This looks like

```
C:\path\to\folder>
```

and python commands (really, lines of code) are typed into a python console, which looks like

```
>>>
```

You are typing a windows command into a python console, which won't work.

If you run `py -3` at a Windows console then you will start a python process and get a python console.

You can run Windows commands from a python console by using python's `subprocess` library:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run("py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CMD to install your dependency.
Run it in CMD
Command: `py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py`